# Send coins from another adress

Tags: wallet, client, bitcoin-core, address, sending

Newbie here!

I need to confirm something:
I have bought bitcoins and I already see them in the QT client I am using.
I now want to send the bitcoins using a different address than the one I use to receive them.
Do I have to send the bitcoins to another address and only then send them again to the final destination?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can only spend bitcoins from the Address they were sent to. Think of it like cheques - only the person they are written out to can authorise them - not their spouse or child. Bitcoin transactions operate similarly.